# How to post rundeck job result to webhook

Tags: webhooks, rundeck

How to post rundeck job result to webhook?

In the rundeck job UI, I could choose
"webhook" option, but what to put into that box?

I know how to post to webhook writing a command line 
in python, but don't know what to do with rundeck.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass webhook variables to an url predefined to receive it, like:

```
http://server/callback?id=${execution.id}&status=${execution.status}&trigger=${notification.trigger}
```

You can see complete reference here:

https://rundeck.org/docs/manual/notifications/webhooks.html

And you have a good CGI example to receive Webhooks parameters:

https://gist.github.com/gschueler/4219733